Using .story files for python Pitest
Hello i am new to pytest and was wondering how are SQL .story files interpreted in pytest and if there any best practices when doing so.
Example of story
  Narrative:
Check if data parameter exists in column1 

    Scenario: Example1
    
    Given <parameters>
    When SQL to execute:
    SELECT  
        column1 
    from table 
    where column1 = '%Data_Entity'
    
    Examples:
    |parameters|
    |Data_Entity=parameter;|

